# How to make backbutton work for a control, not just Page in UWP?

Tags: win-universal-app, back-button, windows-10-mobile

I followed this link http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps and "successfully" make my button work. I mean I can make my backbutton work between **pages**. However, if I navigate to a **control** which is inside this page and will cover the whole screen, then it would not allow me to back to the page. I will stuck in that control.
 I'm wondering how to solve this problem. Currently I can think two possible ways (0) Override OnBackRequested() inside the control's code behind or viewmodel? (1) Override OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed() inside the control's code behind or viewmodel?. I don't know if these are correct way to do it or there is some better way to do it. Another reason for me to override is that I need to make some changes to the page navigation behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed, you simply need to hide the control again when the back button is pressed or back is requested in some other way. I would listen for the `BackRequested` event (not the `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` event) in the page's code-behind, and in the handling method you can check to see if the control is currently shown. The reason I recommend the `BackRequested` event is because it is universal, while `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` only works on a phone. Anyway, if the control is visible, then hide it, and set the `Handled` property of the event arguments to `true`. If the control is already hidden, don't do anything special to handle the event (because in that case you will want the navigation system to handle it by navigating to the previous page, if there is one). There are many aspects to navigation in Windows 10 -- please see these pages on [Navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187344.aspx) and [the SystemNavigationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager.aspx).

Comment: I found a few problems with SystemNavigationManager. Its scope is global which means that no matter which inside which control, once you press the Back, every BackPressed will  be triggered. I tried to set the control to hidden, for some it will work, some just doesn't work. And for those that work, it is kind of difficult to set it to visible again.

Comment: You could try setting up the BackRequested event handler in the code-behind or viewmodel, instead of in App.xaml.cs like the article you referenced shows. That way, you can easily handle the back button per-page instead of globally. On a side note, I'd recommend checking out [Template 10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) which has a robust navigation model with a custom BackRequested event (BootStrapper.BackRequested). This way you can navigate to previous pages or do something like closing a dialogue without much difficulty.